# How to make javascriptcomplete work without shortcut in vim?

Tags: vim

As I found out, there are some differences between csscomplete and javascriptcomplete using the default omnicomplete function. In the css file I type "c", then the suggestion menu show up automatically, I don't even use the  shortcut.

But in the javascript file I type "d", the menu doesn't show up, until I type "ctrl-x ctrl-o".

I don't want to type the shortcut every time so, how can I make the javascriptcomplete same behavior with csscomplete? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you have to type Ctrl-X Ctrl-O to invoke the Omni completion; you're probably using the *AutoComplPop* plugin to have the completion menu open automatically. This plugin supports omni completion for Ruby, Python, Xml, HTML, and CSS, but not JavaScript.

Based on the existing languages, it's probably not too difficult to extend the support to JavaScript. If you're comfortable with Vimscript, you can try this yourself, then submit a patch to the plugin author. Otherwise, you'd have to kindly ask the author for help.

Alternatively, you could rethink your approach. For example, I have rebound Ctrl+Space to trigger omnicompletion:

```
inoremap <expr> <C-Space> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' : '<C-x><C-o>'
```

Comment: Yes you got me! I am using the acp plugin. and thanks for you answer! helps a log.

Answer (score 0):

If Ingo is right and you use AutoComplPop, you might be interested in the small changes I've made to this plugin [here](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/bundle/autocomplpop/autoload/acp.vim#L130), [here](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/bundle/autocomplpop/plugin/acp.vim#L33) and [here](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/bundle/autocomplpop/plugin/acp.vim#L92) to make it work with JavaScript (and PHP).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using "neocomplcache" instead of "autocomplpop". It also supports javascript autocompletion and has more flexibility than autocomplpop. You can even make neocomplcache behave like autocomplpop.

Check here: https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.